# React - Highcharts Full Screen black bar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to implement an application using `highcharts/highstock` and I'm facing a problem trying to use the full screen function.

I need to set a fixed hight to my charts and be able to view each chart from my page as a full screen one, but since the height is fixed it stays the same when full screen loads, I've tried the approach from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253658/remove-fixed-height-for-full-screen-highcharts) post but it's not working, if I set height to 100% the chart overflows the page and gets crooped depending on the aspect ratio of the screen.

I´ve also found [this](https://jsfiddle.net/frenzzy/3qbgs9ub/) working demo, I can't replicate this one. I'm not sure how he's calling the component, also I don't know how the export module (hamburguer menu) is showing up if it's never called.

```js
render() {
    return <div className="chart" ref={ref => this.container = ref} />
  }
```

on my application I'm calling the component this way

```js
render() {
  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      constructorType="stockChart"
      options={options}
      allowChartUpdate
      callback={this.afterChartCreated}
    />
  )
}
```

I tried passing an `ID` to this element to try to set `height` via CSS but it doesn't work.

I was trying to replicate my application with a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-full-screen-yfc0t?file=/src/CustomGUIChart.js), I could only do it on a codesandbox because of import structure, but for some reason full screen is not working there, it prompts this message

> Full screen is not supported inside a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/frenzzy/3qbgs9ub/https://) creates the chart without using Highcharts React wrapper - it's a combination of pure Highcharts JS and React - that's why export menu shows without called it. The [Highcharts React wrappers](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/blob/master/src/HighchartsReact.js) work similarly, but more in 'React way' and gives other opportunities to manage the component.

Back to your issue - I think that a better approach will be defining the height of the Highcharts component as inline React styling. You can achieve by setting it in `containerProps` object.

```
    <CardContent style={{ padding: 0 }}>
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        containerProps={{ style: { height: "400px" } }}
        options={options}
        allowChartUpdate
      />
    </CardContent>
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-full-screen-253sq?file=/src/CustomGUIChart.js

To test it use the `open in new window` codesandbox option (button just above the exporting menu hamburger).